# Is there a way (some sort of API) in node to programatically call local npm publish, other than through spawning

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get the list of files from a local package that would be published by npm. The best solution I've come by is to use

```
npm publish --dry-run
```

through `child_processes.spawn(...)` or a related method.

However, this is not very reliable as I need to parse the text output that is not guaranteed to be/stay the same in all environments/future releases.

Of course, I could `npm pack` and list the contents of the tarball, but that is rather outside the scope of my project, as for instance I wouldn't want to rely on being able to write to the filesystem.

So, is there a "semantic" way to access the data returned by `npm publish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. The specific case I was having trouble with was solved using the `json` option that I was not aware of at the time I posted the question:

   ```
   npm pack --dry-run --json
   ```

   through `child_processes.spawn`, which at least produces semantic results.
2. To the general question, i.e., whether it was possible to call `npm` functions directly, not through spawning, the answer seems to be NO.

   I tried installing `npm` as a library:

   ```
   npm install npm
   ```

   and then in the javascript source

   ```
   const Pack = require('npm').Pack;
   ```

   resulted in an enlightening

   > Error: The programmatic API was removed in npm v8.0.0